# How can i merge two different array of object with having one same key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to merge two different array of objects which having one same key value.

here are my two array of objects.

```
arr1 = [{id:1,name:'amit',age:23},{id:2,name:'akash',age:24},{id:3,name:'arun',age:22}];

arr2 = [{id:1, add : 'india'},{id:3, add:'india'},{id:2,add:'india'}];
```

I want to merge these two array into one array with complete data .

```
arr3 = [{id:1,name:'amit',age:23, add:'india'},{id:2,name:'akash',age:24, add:'india'},{id:3,name:'arun',age:22,add:'india'}];
```

i try to do this but could not get the desired result.

```
var arr3 = _.map(arr1, function(item){
                                      return _.extend(item, _.findWhere(arr2, { id: item.id }));
                                  });
```

there can be some empty array which can cause changes.
i want to avoid two for loops and then one if condition because it will increase complexity. if anyone have better solution for this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: `arr1.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, arr2.find(x => x.id == item.id)));`

Comment: it did not worked.

Comment: the code results in `[{id:1,name:'amit',age:23,add:'india'},{id:2,name:'akash',age:24,add:'india'},{id:3,name:'arun',age:22,add:'india'}]` - which part of that is different to your expectation? Perhaps you've written down the wrong expected result? But the code produces exactly what you specified

Comment: i just change one this in my code and it worked for me.

Comment: there are some empty array too maybe that's why it not worked.

Comment: the code produces the required output when given the input shown in the question - if your input is different than shown, then how do you expect an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give the desired result.
`_.each` will iterate the `arr3` and perform the action.

```
// copies arr1 to arr3
var arr3 = Array.from(arr1);
_.each(arr3, (item) => {
   // extends another object to the current object (item from arr3)
   _.extend(item, _.find(arr2, (a) => a.id == item.id));
})
```

We will get the desired result in `arr3`

Comment: i use findWhere instead of find and it worked ! is there any difference between find and findWhere.

Comment: [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) vs [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find)

Answer (score 0):

You can use loadash merge

```
var arr3 = _.merge(arr1, arr2)
```